# How to write TSQL insert stored procedure with max value of previous serial numbers?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have `Letters` table:

```
+--------------+-------+
| SerialNumber | Letter|
+--------------+-------+
| 1            | A     |
| 2            | B     |
| 3            | C     |
| 4            | D     |
+--------------+-------+
```

How to write TSQL insert stored procedure PA_Letters_INS which automatically adds max of previous serial number values and has `letter` insert parameter (without MSSQL autoincrement functionality on `SerialNumber` column).

(exec PA_Letters_INS 'E' adds {5, E} record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Letter` being you Stored Procedure Parameter,

```
INSERT INTO Letters(SerialNumber, Letter)
     SELECT MAX(SerialNumber) + 1, @Letter 
     FROM Letters
```

Comment: This will work if the table is not empty. For the general case use COALESCE(MAX(SerialNumber),0)